# Passing context in Android Java is no good but how do you access activity in services?

Tags: java, android, android-context

I know passing static context is a no-on and should be avoided. I understand the reasoning behind it.

The question I have is, how can we access certain calls that need "Activity" in their arguments. Such as:

```
public class BackgroundServiceParent extends Service implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
            .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
            .useDefaultAccount()
            .addConnectionCallbacks(
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
....

if (!result.hasResolution()) {
    // Show the localized error dialog

    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(),
     (Activity) applicationContext, 0).show();
      return;
}

if (!authInProgress) {
    try {
        authInProgress = true;
        result.startResolutionForResult((Activity) applicationContext, REQUEST_OAUTH);
         } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
             Log.e(TAG,
             Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}
}
```

Any help in understanding the best approach in this case is appreciated.

Comment: You may need to rethink your design: you're attempting to spawn a dialog from a background, non-UI component - does this sound like a good idea :-)?

Comment: It is part of a foreground service. I'm not sure with a foreground service if it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

You don't, accessing activity from a service is bad. You can use binder to get service instance in your activity, then you can register some callbacks in your service to communicate with your activity. Check out this link for an example https://gist.github.com/ErikHellman/4b6ecc87d1b37c9809d1

Comment: there are many ways to communicate from a service to your activity. Handlers, Broadcast receivers and Interfaces.